# I got a new bluetooth headphones and I have a delay. is there a solution?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, headphones

Today I got some new Bluetooth headphones (i900000 max - Airpods Pro replica) and I know what you'll say - "You got a replica of Airpods, what did you expect?", but hey, I read a review before I bought them and people said that there is no delay, but I have a little delay when watching videos.. I'm using an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy A8 2018) and the only codec that the headphones support is `SBC`. Is there something I can do to fix the delay?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the review also mention about Android devices or only iOS? Android has a known Bluetooth audio latency issue as explained in the linked question.

Comment: most of the review is on ios but I think that the review that I saw is from people that using ios.but how is this possible that in ios there is not delay and in android there is a little ?

Comment: there is something I can do to improve it a little at least on youtube ?

Comment: When buying Bluetooth headsets make sure the headseat and your Android device support `aptX Low Latency` codec. Using this codec the delay is usually acceptable.

Comment: OK, but know is there something to do with these headphones that supports only SBC codec to reduce the delay ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do. That's how those headphones are designed to work.

Comment: There is nothing to do to improve it at little ? at least at youtube videos ?